# C++-Fortran mixcompile unresolved externals

Tags: c++, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to make a fortran-C++ mix compile project. I use the case to test how the visual studio 2017 compiler link the intel fortran .lib file. Here is the example code:

Fortran code here:

```
!DEC$ IF DEFINED (_DLL)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: ADD
!DEC$ END IF
REAL*8 FUNCTION ADD (A, B, C, D) 
REAL*8 B,D
INTEGER*4 A,C
DIMENSION B(4), D(4)
ADD = B(A) + D(C)
RETURN
END
```

C++ code here:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {double add_(int *, double[], int *, double[]); }

double ar1[4] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
double ar2[4] = { 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0 };

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    double z;

    x = 3;
    y = 3;


    z = add_(&x, ar1, &y, ar2); /* Call Fortran add routine */
    /* Note: Fortran indexes arrays 1..n */
    /* C indexes arrays 0..(n-1) */

    std::cout << z << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The project setup procedures are:

1. Open VS studio, create a c++ empty project, add the c++ code in the source file. Solution will be automatically created as well.
2. Add a new fortran static library project in the solution. Add the fortran code in the source file.
3. Fortran project-> properties->Libraries->Runtime Libraries-> Debug multithread dll.
4. Build the fortran project, find the .lib file directory.
5. C++ project-> linker -> General -> Additional Library Dependencies -> add the .lib file directory here
6. C++ project-> linker -> Input -> Additional dependencies -> Add .lib file name here end with ";".
7. Build C++ project.

And the compiler error message is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Cpp_main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _add_ referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Documents\TEST_Project\MixCompile_Test\Mix_compile\Debug\Cpp_main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Cpp_main.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why the compiler cannot resolve the external function call even if I assign the .lib directory in C++ project?

Thanks a lot!

---

Update 22-6-24:
Thank you Steve. I followed your instruction and made configuration in VC++ directories to add the ifortran include and lib directory into it. But new problem happened:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Cpp_main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprtd.lib'
1>Done building project "Cpp_main.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

Update 22-06-24
I solved the issue. I will upload the whole solution tomorrow. It's really special  problem for VS2017.

Fortran compiler: Inter ifortran19
Cpp compiler: MSVC 2017

Step:

1. Create your CPP project and solution.
2. In the solution, add a fortran static library project with name .
3. Add your fortran headfile and source code in that project.
4. For every fortran subroutine that will be called in CPP, do like this:

   subroutine_name() BIND(C)
   USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

   end subroutine
5. For CPP headfile, if the fortran compiler is interl fortran, do not add underscore_ after the function name!! Just declare the function name with extern "C" like this:
   extern "C"{void <fortran_subroutine>()}
   Remember, all the arguments passed from C code should be reference or pointer. Do not pass value.
6. In the C compiler, add several dependency directories:

   6.1 C project properties-> VC++ Directories -> Include Directries -> add $(IFORT_COMPILER19)\compiler\include;

   6.2 C project properties-> VC++ Directories -> Libiary Directries -> add $(IFORT_COMPILER19)\compiler\lib; (+\ia32_win or +\intel64_win depend on win32 or X64 compiler used in VS)
7. In the C linker, add several dependency directories:

   7.1 C project properties-> linker-> General-> Additional Dependency Directories->
   add  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib
   (+\x86 or +\x64 depend on win32 or x64 compiler used in VS)

   7.2 C project properties-> linker-> General-> Additional Dependency Directories->
   add the fortran static library compiled  file directory

   7.3 C project properties-> linker->input add .lib
8. In the source code, include the header file with extern “C” keyword declaration and call the function
   <fortran_subroutine>()

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: Sorry! I added it unintentionally.

Comment: Did you consider using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -so  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` for C++, and `gfortran -Wall -Wextra -g` for Fortran- and some Linux distribution (like [Debian](https://debian.org/)....). Then mixing C++ and Fortran is easier (if you read the documentation)

Answer (score 3):

The linker (not the compiler) can't resolve the reference because the naming conventions don't match. You named the C routine "add_" in lowercase and with a trailing underscore. Neither of those are part of the default Intel Fortran conventions.

A second problem is that your directives to export the name into the DLL are outside the routine - they will be ignored. (Not that this matters if you are building a static library.)

The simplest and most portable way to fix this is:

1. Remove the trailing underscore from `add_` in the C source, wherever it appears.
2. Add `BIND(C)` at the end of the `SUBROUTINE` line in the Fortran source.
3. Move the directives inside the routine.

This will make the names match, not just in Intel Fortran but any other combination of Fortran and C you may use.

I would also recommend replacing the non-standard Fortran variable declarations and use this instead:

```
    REAL(C_DOUBLE) FUNCTION ADD (A, B, C, D) BIND(C)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING
!DEC$ IF DEFINED (_DLL)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: ADD
!DEC$ END IF
    REAL(C_DOUBLE) :: B,D
    INTEGER(C_INT) :: A,C
    ...
```